# access environment variables from the .yaml file in my jest test file

Tags: unit-testing, testing, jestjs, mocking, environment-variables

In the attached folder is my folder structure.

[image]

There are a few environment variables defined in my template.yaml file for my rds connection, the values of which are in the parameter store in my aws console. I access them in my index.js file as 'process.env.DB_name', 'process.env.DB_PASSWORD' and so on.. but i get those values as undefined in my index.test.js file. Online blogs suggest to assign the value to process.env variables on the fly in the tests and restore them back to the original as so:

```
const original = process.env.DB_NAME;
process.env.DB_NAME = 'database name';
process.env.DB_NAME = original;
```

but I don't want my values to be exposed as I am connecting to a test mysql database for my tests on my rds instance. Is there a way I could assign the values anonymously using mock functions or any other way.?